# How to Switch context to an Imbedded Web Page and get the current URL using Appium for an iOS app?

Tags: java, ios, webview, ui-automation, appium-ios

I am trying to verify that a web link in my mobile app redirects to the correct URL using appium. I was able to do this easily in Android by just using context switching. However I can't get it to work in iOS. I have read dozens of other posts and threads but they have not been helpful

```java
public String getURL(){
        appContext = ((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).getContext();
        Set<String> contextList = ((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).getContextHandles();
        ((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).context((String) contextList.toArray()[1]);
        return driver.getCurrentUrl();
    }
```

contextList always only contains 1 element in iOS, NATIVE_APP. For Android I get 2, NATIVE_APP and WEBVIEW.

I tired just using

```java
public String getURL(){
        return driver.getCurrentUrl();
    }
```

for iOS but then I get a "method not implemented" error

Is there a better way to get the url from an imbedded app Webview? I just want to get the url as a string so a can perform an `Assert.assertEqual` on it.

Note: `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` is enabled

**EDIT**: Looks like there is an issue with newer versions of iOS 16 that prevents SafariViews from being debuggable. Devs are looking into how to configure app to allow it.